# How often do you Upgrade your Bug Tracking System / Software

Tags: upgrade, bug-tracking, fogbugz

I am using Fogbugz as my Bug tracking software, and was thinking on a schedule so that I can upgrade my Bug tracking software once in a while according to that schedule.

I was just curious on how others are doing their upgrades, and how often.

It would also be nice If you share on what basis you schedule the frequency of your Bug tracking software's upgradation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I check for the changes implemented in any software and see if the new feature set and/or fixes provide benefit to our development team. In the case of FogBugz, I have not had a single problem caused by the upgrades. Fog Creek has done a remarkable job at testing their product before it hits our system.

I am not saying FogBugz is perfect, but it is close. I cannot say this about every software vendor. I really dislike when software installs screw up the workstations or the server. I use to be a jump on the new release as soon as it ships kinda guy. But too much blood loss being on the bleeding edge these days so I now wait a little bit and see who else has success or failure.

By the way, this is a business decision, not a technical decision. And I make it on a case-by-case basis depending on the reliability of the vendor and the level of importance the software makes to my company.

Rick Schummer

Answer (score 1):

Whenever we need to. If running an older version still works, then thats what we'll do. If a new version has features that would aid development, then we'd upgrade after the next release of our product.

If we were to upgrade just because one became available, the response is usually that the bug tracking software is not as important as fixing the bugs themselves, and that it could wait.

Answer (score -2):

There is no software free of bugs, even the bug tracking softwares.